# Remove TOC and Bibliography Titles Chapter Numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, report

I am using the `report` document class and I ran into a bit of a weird quirk. Both the TOC and Bibliography have a chapter number which is quite surprising. See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

% figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter.~}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\input{title}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%Introduction
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Intro}
\clearpage

%
\chapter{Chap1}
\clearpage

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

It looks like
[image: TOC]

[image: Bibliography]

Would be grateful for any advice on how to remove those numbers as it looks quite weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the "Contents" and "Bibliography" headers are typeset using the same `\chapter` method that you redefined to include the chapter number. Your MWE doesn't output the bibliography portion, but using the `tocloft` package we can fix at least the TOC portion.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter.~}
\usepackage{tocloft} %<--
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bf\LARGE} %<--
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Chap1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! This worked great for the TOC. Also you are right regarding the modification. That is quite interesting.